# You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered. (React+ReactROuterDom v6)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

So this might be hard to get at first but I'll try to explain everything possible. I'm rendering an App component which uses `useNavigation` hook from `react-router-dom` library. Inside `AppRoutes` I check, if I have `$stateParams.redirect` and also other values like `param1` and `param2`.I get `$stateParams` from another custom hook defined in my app. While running the app, I get the log, `should navigate now` but it actually doesn't navigate to `decider-route` page instead it stays at `/` which is `<Home />` component. Also I have this warning in console `You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.` I was wondering why doesn't the navigation takes place to `decider-route` and the warning is the reason why navigation does not take place?

```
    const App = () => {
        return (
        <MemoryRouter>
          <AppRoutes />
        </MemoryRouter>
      )
    }
    
    const AppRoutes = () => {
      const navigate = useNavigate()                // react-router-dom v6
    
      if ($stateParams.redirect) {
        if ($stateParams.param1 && $stateParams.param2) {
          console.log('StateParams : ', $stateParams)
          console.log('Should navigate now!')
          navigate(`/decider-route/${$stateParams.param1}/${$stateParams.param2}`)
        }
      }
    
      return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="/decider-route/:param1/:param2"
            element={<Component />}
          />
        </Routes>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error is preety much self-explanatory. You just need to wrap the `navigate()` in a `useEffect()` hook so that it gets executed after the component mounts.

But, in this case, it is being called as soon as the component is first rendered.

`navigate()` should be triggered by a user action or an useEffect hook in this case. But you're not playing by the rules :)

**app.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <AppRoutes />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );
};

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // react-router-dom v6

  useEffect(() => {
    if ($stateParams.redirect) {
      if ($stateParams.param1 && $stateParams.param2) {
        console.log("StateParams : ", $stateParams);
        console.log("Should navigate now!");
        navigate(
          `/decider-route/${$stateParams.param1}/${$stateParams.param2}`
        );
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/decider-route/:param1/:param2 " element={<Component />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is there an existing explanation for why the rules forbid calling `navigate` when the calling component is first rendered?